# View.Layout() for adding Views

Tags: android, android-layout, view, android-custom-view

I am confused on how to create views (programmatically) inside a RelativeLayout. Currently I am using .layout to position views (created in java) inside the RelativeLayout but if I try to add a view using LayoutParams to position the view & without using .layout, those views aren't added to the relativelayout. Why is that?

```
public class MyCustomRelativeLayout extends RelativeLayout
{

 public void addViews(){
  MyCustomImageView myImage = new MyCustomImageView(context);
  myImage.setLayoutParams(new LayoutParams(WRAP_CONTENT, WRAP_CONTENT));
  myImage.setImageResource(R.drawable.ic_launcher); 
  addView(myImage); // this one isn't visible/added in RelativeLayout.


  ImageView image = new ImageView(context);
  image.layout(0,0,300,400);
  image.setImageResource(R.drawable.garden);
  addView(image); // this one is visible/added in Relativelayout
 }
}

public class MyCustomImageView extends ViewGroup
{
   public void onLayout(int l, int t, int r, int b)
   {
       this.layout(l,t,r,b);
   }

   public void addImageViews()
   {
      ImageView mImage = new ImageView(context);
      mImage.layout(0,0,200,200);
      mImage.setImageResource(R.drawable.hello);
      addView(mImage); // this one is visible/added in Relativelayout

      ImageView mImage2 = new ImageView(context);
      mImage2.layout(0,0,70,70);
      mImage2.setImageResource(R.drawable.hello2);
      addView(mImage2); // this one is visible/added in Relativelayout
   }
}
```

Why is this happening? 
`And When to use .layout instead of LayoutParams?`

Best Regards

Comment: where is the onLayout implementations of the ViewGroup's subclass?

Answer (score 1):

LayoutParams dosn't inflate the View. It just describe to the parents how he sholuld inflate the View.